# Can you setup a Chainlink function where the end user pays the LINK gas fee?

Tags: gas, chainlink, server-side, api, nextjs

I was watching this video https://youtu.be/nKRZ1R2BC4Q. Chainlink functions look incredible. I have a Next.js app that I plan on integrating a Chainlink function. This Chainlink function will take the place of the Next.js app's `pages/api` route. `pages/api` runs on the server, so adding a `pages/api` route makes it not static (dynamic). Dynamic apps aren't immutable because servers fail, go down, change IP addresses, etc... Swapping the `pages/api` with a Chainlink function would make my app sudo-immutable.

The only problem that I see is that the consumer contract controlling the function needs to be funded with LINK. The biggest problem here would be that app users could drain the consumer contract's funds with no consequence.

So is there a way to make the end user pay the LINK gas fee directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chainlink Functions rely on [subscriptions](https://docs.chain.link/chainlink-functions/resources/subscriptions#overview) that are controlled by an EOA (the admin).  This subscriptions holds the LINK.  But any wallet can *add funds* to a subscription even if they dont own it  as this funding is done via the [transferAndCall method](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/blob/develop/contracts/src/v0.4/LinkToken.sol#L27) on the LINK token contract

So you would need to design your front end to have users add to your subscription and then implement tracking logic, or a flat fee logic or whatever funding tracking logic makes sense for your use case.

Comment: Oh this is great! Just to confirm... this transferAndCall method actually allows funding and executing the link contract in the same transaction?

Comment: Christian, yes as per ERC677 standard. You can read about how LINK tokens use it here:
https://docs.chain.link/resources/link-token-contracts

Answer (score -1):

Please take a look at this much simpler method for enabling end-users to pay for gas fees automatically without holding cryptocurrency: https://hackernoon.com/how-to-automatically-pay-your-end-users-gas-fees-without-hodling-crypto